# Android/Retrofit HAL JSON support

Tags: android, json, retrofit, hal-json

I'm using Retrofit in my Android project to handle REST web service calls. Now I need to add support HAL JSON to be able to implement dynamic adding items to my list (load more on scrool).
HalJson: http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html

Does anybody know how to handle it with Retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

**Gson-HAL Implementation** [(Library Link)](https://github.com/XPBytes/com.xpbytes.gson.hal)

Above library will explain the object creation

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
.registerTypeAdapterFactory(new HalTypeAdapterFactory())
.create();
```

**Retrofit Implementation**

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
            .build();
```

It has some [Missing](https://github.com/XPBytes/com.xpbytes.gson.hal#missing) components which can be work around by modifying the library

Comment: It looks unfinished and abandoned. Isn't there anything else?

Comment: I found this the most simplest impl, other then this u have to write your own ApapterFactory and Destabilization logic. other lib but need some work https://github.com/Nykredit/jackson-dataformat-hal